# Can I get useful information from crash information like this?

Tags: c#, ios, debugging, crash, crash-reports

I am using Xamarin.iOS, which is a C# wrapper around Objective-C. This debugging question for C#.

I have a crash that happened in a Task, but that information is not useful, here it is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.AggregateException', reason: 'System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () <0x100b32280 + 0x004b4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () <0x100b2ed80 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () <0x100b28ee0 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) <0x100b78c70 + 0x00097> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) <0x100b6f700 + 0x0008f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue () <0x100b32280 + 0x004b4> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read () <0x100b2ed80 + 0x00057> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAndMoveToContent () <0x100b28ee0 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) <0x100b78c70 + 0x00097> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) <0x100b6f700 + 0x0008f> in <filename unknown>:0 <---
```

From this, I know that somewhere I have a JSON being deserialised that received HTML (starts with `<`).

Now I was scrolling through the rest of the crash information, and I started thinking about this information:

```
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib               0x000000018ca1c16c 0x18ca1b000 + 4460
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018da17cec 0x18d93b000 + 904428
2   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018da15908 0x18d93b000 + 895240
3   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018d944048 0x18d93b000 + 36936
4   CFNetwork                            0x000000018e135fd0 0x18e067000 + 847824
5   Foundation                           0x000000018e55347c 0x18e449000 + 1090684
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018cb00850 0x18cafd000 + 14416
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018cb00760 0x18cafd000 + 14176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000018cafddac 0x18cafd000 + 3500
```

What do these numbers signify? And can I retrieve which file or even which method was called from these numbers?

Comment: You can symbolicate these numbers with Xcode or with atos terminal command- https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above crash information is showing list of active frames during crash

```
1   CoreFoundation                       0x000000018da17cec 0x18d93b000 + 904428
```

Details of above sample frame

```
1 : Frame Number

CoreFoundation : Framework Name

0x000000018da17cec : Address of the called Function

0x18d93b000 : File Name

+8740 : Line of the Code
```

To get function name and file name from address, we need to symbolicate crash report.

Part of crash log you posted in this question is showing all default iOS frameworks, so even after symbolication you may not get that much useful information for it. You need to look for a active frame with App name, that may give you useful information.

There are many third party libraries available which we can use for crash reporting, like Fabric, Hockey App, Flurry.

[Hockey ap](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/) seems to have support for Xamarin, hope it helps.

Comment: All I had to do was symbolicate the report. I now use hockeyApp, and I upload my dsyms to them each time I upload a build, so that each crash can be symbolicated immediately